# Adobe Air and .NET

Tags: .net, air, adobe

I Adobe Air completly JavaScript? Can't I use a .NET language like VB.NET or C#.NET?

Thanks

Comment: You can also use ActionScript 3 or Flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use .NET with Adobe AIR,

visit : [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/first_im_app.html)

Also stay tuned to Adobe's site as they can announce a plug in for Visual Studio 2008 any time (that supports Flex)

meanwhile you can use this [another supported plugin](http://blog.flashgen.com/2008/12/02/sapphiresteel-produce-visual-studio-flex-plugin/)

Comment: Excellent! I was awaiting this.

Answer (score 2):

As the official answer states, Adobe Air does not support .Net languages.  If you are looking for something similar for Windows desktop programming that does support .Net I would suggest [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).  The [WPF Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917) book is pretty good if you want to come up to speed quickly.

WPF is build into .Net 3.0 and 3.5, and runs on WinXP SP2, Vista, and Win2k3 and Win2k8 Servers.

**Note**:  This was written when another answer was marked as the accepted "official" answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use .net language directly in Adobe AIR apps (at least not yet). The best solution is to proxy calls between the AIR app and .net code:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/

mike chambers

mesh@adobe.com

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use .NET languages for Adobe Air.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot use .Net to write Adobe AIR apps directly, you can only consume(provide data to AIR apps) any backend services that uses .NET, PHP, Java, or Coldfusion. You can only create adobe Adobe AIR apps with Flex, Actionscript in Flash/Flex Builder or Javascript/HTML/CSS(Ajax) in Flash Pro.